# C + JNI: CallStaticCharMethod causes error

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm trying to couple a Java and a C program with JNI. My goal is to pass a String from JNI to C. I'm getting a error (segmentation fault?) when calling CallStaticCharMethod. I have the feeling that I'm really missing the point of how to do it. What am I missing?

The example I modified comes from [here](http://hildstrom.com/projects/jni/index.html) .

**helloWorld.java**

```
public class helloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
public static char hello(){
        String s = "H";
        char c = s.charAt( 0 );
        return c;
    }
}
```

**hello_world.c**

```
JNIEnv *create_vm(JavaVM **jvm) {
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./";
    args.options = &options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    int rv;
    rv = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void **) &env, &args);
    if (rv < 0 || !env)
        printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n", rv);
    else
        printf("Launched JVM! :)\n");
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv *env) {
    jclass hello_world_class;
    jmethodID main_method;
    jmethodID hello_method;
    jint number = 20;
    jint exponent = 3;   
    hello_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, hello_world_class, "hello", "()C");

    //This line causes the error:
    (*env)->CallStaticCharMethod(env, hello_world_class, hello_method);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);
    if (env == NULL)
        return 1;
    invoke_class(env);
    return 0;
    }
```

**Edit 1**

This is in the error log:

```
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6f112a]  
JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg::JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg(_jmethodID*, _va_list_tag*)+0xa
```

Comment: Shouldn't the method signature be `()C`?

Comment: I tried Ljava/lang/Character and Ljava/lang/C as well, but that doesn't help. But it could be that this wrong, but there's another mistake...

Comment: `char` is a primitive type, so you shouldn't use `Ljava/lang` in the signature. It's just `C`.

Comment: Thank you both, I changed it to ()C. I still get the error, which is now added to the question.

Comment: Well, you never initialize `hello_world_class`. Also, you should check the return values of all JNI calls (and check for exceptions when something can throw).

Comment: Should I initialize it even through I access a static method?

Comment: Of course. `CallStatic<Type>Method` needs a reference to the class that the method belongs to.

Comment: Yes, get the class like the following.  I'm not sure if converting to a global ref is necessary for classes, but I do it with all JNI objects just to be safe:
jclass cls = env->FindClass(className);
jclass globalCls = static_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(cls));
env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the initialize the `hello_world_class` as commenters above proposed. Note the `hello_world_class` is not an instance of class helloWorld. It is a reference to class - that means reference to type. Your C code knows the method name only but it does not know the class name. The method `hello` can be defined in a lot of classes and C code must know what class it is:

```
hello_world_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "helloWorld");
hello_method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, hello_world_class, "hello", "()C");
```

It is not necessary to have a global reference in this case. Simple `FindClass` is sufficient.